# Azure Active Directory: Where is the MFA verified phone number stored?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Once a user verifies their phone number through Azure Active Directory B2C via Multi-Factor Authentication, where is this data and other metadata about the device stored? Where can developers access it because I can only find information when you deploy an on-premise solution the documentation does not detail anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the same for B2C users, but for normal AAD users this info is stored in AAD in the `StrongAuthenticationPhoneAppDetails` and `StrongAuthenticationUserDetails` attributes.

Comment: where can I access this `StrongAuthenticationPhoneAppDetails` object?

Comment: I found it using AAD PowerShell: `(get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName user@domain.onmicrosoft.com).StrongAuthenticationPhoneAppDetails`

Comment: yeah no way to get it from Azure cloud via graph api atm

Comment: Yeah, it looks like powershell calls the `provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com` web service, not the graph API.

Comment: unfortunately impossible to access it programmatically outside...going to come back to this question when they hopefully implement some access to it...I mean it's so trivial to have access to MFA phone number...but I understand its still in preview so...

Comment: any updates on this? I also need to access the number used for MFA through web app code.